# Regex pattern for underscore or hyphen but not both

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that is allowing a string to be standalone, separated by hyphen and underscore.

I need help so the string only takes hyphen or underscore, but not both.

This is what I have so far.

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)([-_]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$

foo             = passed
foo-bar         = passed
foo_bar         = passed
foo-bar-baz     = passed
foo_bar_baz     = passed
foo-bar_baz_qux = passed # but I don't want it to
foo_bar-baz-quz = passed # but I don't want it to
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using the regex in.

Comment: Note that if you want to match `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`  you could use `\w` in its place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may expand the pattern a bit and use a backreference to only match the same delimiter:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:([-_])[a-z0-9]+(?:\1[a-z0-9]+)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZdNba/1/)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z][a-z0-9]*`  - a letter followed with 0+ lowercase letters or digits
- `(?:([-_])[a-z0-9]+(?:\1[a-z0-9]+)*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `([-_])` - Capture group 1 matching either `-` or `_`
  - `[a-z0-9]+` - 1+ lowercase letters or digits
  - `(?:\1[a-z0-9]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `\1` - the same value as in Group 1
    - `[a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more lowercase letters or digits
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: When declared in a C string literal, the backslash must be doubled: `String s = "^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:([-_])[a-z0-9]+(?:\\1[a-z0-9]+)*)?$"` (Java).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice clean solution:

```
^([a-zA-Z-]+|[a-zA-Z_]+)$
```

Break it down!

- `^` start at the beginning of the text
- `[a-zA-Z-]+` match anything `a-z` or `A-Z` or `-`
- `|` OR operator
- `[a-zA-Z_]+` match anything `a-z` or `A-Z` or `_`
- `$` end at the end of the text

[Here's an example on regexr!](http://regexr.com/3fl8n)

Comment: This one works the best for me, but what if I didn't want the string to begin with '-' or '_' ?

Comment: And why does mine work worse? This `^([a-zA-Z-]+|[a-zA-Z_]+)$` does not actually preserve the initial requirements.

Comment: You could just add a character on each side, i.e.: `^[a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z-]+|[a-zA-Z_]+)[a-zA-Z_]$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yours also works really great. But the way I'm trying to use it through a CSS parser that does not know what /1 is when I want to find the first matching character for - or _.

Comment: What  do you mean by a "CSS parser"? How are you declaring the regex? If it is a string literal, the backslash must be doubled. Please update the question so that we could adjust the patterns. Note it is not `/1`, but `\1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right. It was a string literal and the double backslash works.

Comment: No hard feelings Aaron, it's just Wiktor answers first. But you still get a plus 1. :)

Comment: Man, I got to type faster x)